# How to convert a DER private key to PEM

Tags: openssl, certificate, private-key

I have a private key that is in binary format. I'm not sure if this is DER format but I need to convert it to PEM.

I'm using openssl with this command:

`openssl rsa -inform DER -outform PEM -in test.key -out test.key`

But I get an error:

```
unable to load Private Key
48044:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:../openssl-1.1.1q/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1149:
48044:error:0D06C03A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_d2i_ex_primitive:nested asn1 error:../openssl-1.1.1q/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:713:
48044:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_template_noexp_d2i:nested asn1 error:../openssl-1.1.1q/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:646:Field=version, Type=PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO
48044:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:../openssl-1.1.1q/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1149:
48044:error:0D06C03A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_d2i_ex_primitive:nested asn1 error:../openssl-1.1.1q/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:713:
48044:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_template_noexp_d2i:nested asn1 error:../openssl-1.1.1q/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:646:Field=version, Type=RSAPrivateKey
48044:error:04093004:rsa routines:old_rsa_priv_decode:RSA lib:../openssl-1.1.1q/crypto/rsa/rsa_ameth.c:142:
48044:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:../openssl-1.1.1q/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1149:
48044:error:0D06C03A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_d2i_ex_primitive:nested asn1 error:../openssl-1.1.1q/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:713:
48044:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_template_noexp_d2i:nested asn1 error:../openssl-1.1.1q/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:646:Field=version, Type=PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO
```

How can I obtain a PEM key? Is it possible that it is not a DER key ?

Comment: Are you sure the key type is RSA? Try `ec` in place of `rsa` in that command to check for an elliptic curve key. It might also help knowing where this key came from originally.

Comment: In addition, do not use the same path in `-in` and `-out` as you do not want to lose the original key in case anything goes wrong.

Comment: [Also posted without warning at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77118058/how-to-convert-a-der-private-key-to-pem) which I responded to earlier.